# Hive HBase snapshot query result can't insert into new table

Tags: hive, hbase, integration, snapshot

we are using CDH 5.16.1 ,hbase-1.2.0,hive 1.1.0

The target is i want to accelerate the speed of save some data from hbase to hive. 
  By default I used the HbaseStorageHandler, but it's very slow because it used full scan by request hbase region server. So i tried to query hbase bypass the region server, and directly access the data from underline file.

It was at least 6 times quicker than before when i query hbase with snapshot. But, i can't write the data into hive table, all the fields were null except the row key.

```
drop table if exists test;
create table test as select * from default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table;
```

However if i don't use the snapshot, HbaseStorageHandler can successfully load data into new hive table.

Here are steps i took:

First i have created a Hbase table:

```sql
create 'user_data_table','personal_data','professional_data';
```

Then I inserted few records into the table as

```sql
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:Location','IL'
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:FName','Deb'
put 'user_data_table','user1','personal_data:LName','D'
put 'user_data_table','user1','professional_data:dept','IT'
put 'user_data_table','user1','professional_data:salary','2000'

put 'user_data_table','user2','personal_data:FName','CH'
put 'user_data_table','user2','personal_data:LName','AK'
put 'user_data_table','user2','professional_data:dept','IT'
put 'user_data_table','user2','professional_data:salary','80000'
```

Then i specify the  snapshot.name to make Hive query Hbase bypasses Hbase server, and directly accesses the underlying files.

```sql
set hive.hbase.snapshot.name=snapshot-day-1;
set hive.hbase.snapshot.restoredir=/tmp;

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table1(key string, Location string,FName string,LName string, dept string, salary string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:Location,personal_data:FName,personal_data:LName,professional_data:dept,professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "user_data_table");
```

Finally, when i try to load the query result into hive table as below, the result are  weirdly, all the value of fields were NULL ,except the row key.

```sql
#show hbase table data
hive> select * from default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table;
OK
user1   IL  Deb D   IT  2000
user2   NULL    CH  AK  IT  80000
Time taken: 0.199 seconds, Fetched: 2 row(s)

#load the query result into new table
hive> create table test as select * from default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table;

.... OK

#but all the value of  fields are NULL ,expect the row key.
hive> select * from test;
OK
user1   NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
user2   NULL        NULL    NULL    NULL
```

And i also try to load data without the param " set hive.hbase.snapshot.name ", now it insert query result into table as i expected. (but in this way ,it was very slow, because HBaseStorageHandler query the hbase with full scan with hbase server api )

```sql
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE if not exists default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table1(key string, Location string,FName string,LName string, dept string,salary string) 
STORED BY 'org.apache.hadoop.hive.hbase.HBaseStorageHandler'
WITH SERDEPROPERTIES ("hbase.columns.mapping" = ":key,personal_data:Location,personal_data:FName,personal_data:LName,professional_data:dept,professional_data:salary")
TBLPROPERTIES ("hbase.table.name" = "user_data_table");

 create table test1 as select * from default.hbase_user_data_snapshot1_table;

select * from test1;
OK
user1   IL  Deb D   IT  2000
user2   NULL    CH  AK  IT  80000
the snapshot feature link:
```

i also tried to specify the  hive.hbase.snapshot.name in TBLPROPERTIES,but
the hive query request the Hbase region server API instead of access the underline file directly.
I looked the HbaseStorageHandler source code, it choose whether or not use the HbaseSnapshot  by judging the hive conf property (HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVE_HBASE_SNAPSHOT_NAME)

So if you specify the hive.hbase.snapshot.name in any other place ,it will not available for hive to query hbase with snapshot. And i also changed all the hdfs dir permission to 777,but it still couldn't insert data into hive table,except i didn't use the snapshot. 
It was weirdly I checked the DEBUG log ,but there is not any error in it.

I'm wandering maybe this is a bug about that feature.
(the snapshot feature link:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HBASE-8369)

Anybody can help me ?

Comment: @Tariq  Could u help me with this problem?

Comment: did u try specifying `snapshot name` as **`TBLPROPERTIES ("hive.hbase.snapshot.name"="snapshot-day-1")`** instead of **`hbase.table.name`** in `TBLPROPERTIES`?

Comment: @Shu Yes,i did. But when i specified hive.hbase.snapshot.name in TBLPROPERTIES . The hive query request the Hbase region server API instead of access the underline file directly. I also looked the HbaseStorageHandler source code,it choose whether use HbaseSnapshot or not by judge the hive 
 conf property(HiveConf.ConfVars.HIVE_HBASE_SNAPSHOT_NAME).

Comment: @Shu So if you specify the hive.hbase.snapshot.name in any other place ,it will not available for hive to query hbase with snapshot. And i also changed all the hdfs dir permission to 777,but it still couldn't insert data into hive table,except i didn't use the snapshot.It was weirdly I checked the DEBUG log ,but there is not any error in it. And i was wandering is this a bug of Hive framework?